# How do I get the maximum length for each column using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

How do I get the maximum length for each column using Nokogiri?

Example HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>ONE</td><td>TWO</td><td>THREE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Monaco</td><td>Bangkok</td><td>Thailand</td>
 </tr>    
</table>
```

The result would the string length inside each `<td>`.

```
<td>one</td> => 3
<td>two</td> => 3
<td>three</td> => 5
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would map the length of tr/td:

```
lengths = doc.search('tr').map{|tr| tr.search('td').map{|td| td.text.length}}
=> [[3, 3, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

transpose that to get columns and get just the max from each:

```
lengths.transpose.map &:max
=> [6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: I will try for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the `lengths.transpose.map &:max`? It's nothing return to me in output.

Comment: @lovepong, Ruby 1.8 doesn't understand `&:max` natively. Ruby 1.9+ does. For Ruby 1.8+ use `map { |c| c.max }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**A pure one-liner XPath 2.0 solution**, supposing that the table has *regular* structure (each row has the same number of columns):

```
for $i in 1 to count(/*/tr[1]/td)
 return
    max(/*/tr/td[$i]/string-length())
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "for $i in 1 to count(/*/tr[1]/td)
       return
          max(/*/tr/td[$i]/string-length())
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ONE</td>
        <td>TWO</td>
        <td>THREE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Monaco</td>
        <td>Bangkok</td>
        <td>Thailand</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
6 7 8
```

Comment: unfortunately Nokogiri uses libxml2 and therefore only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: @MarkThomas, I have heard about WebDriver supporting XPath 2.0 ... ?